# Double free error when using Apple LLVM compiler

Tags: objective-c, ios, free, llvm, nslocalizedstring

I have a project written for iOS 4.x. Recently i update it to iOS5 using XCode 4.3.2. It's strange that the app stop everytime with double free error when using Apple LLVM compiler. After i change back to LLVM GCC, it works fine. Is there any difference between this two?
The code is shown below:

```
- (NSArray *)readCourselist {

    NSString *path = [[self currentUserPathString] stringByAppendingPathComponent:kUserCourseListFilename];

    return [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

}

- (NSArray *)getCourselist {

    NSArray *courseRawArray = [self readCourselist];

    for (NSDictionary *courseDic in courseRawArray) {

        CourseModel *courseModel = [[CourseModel alloc] init];

        courseModel.courseID = [[courseDic objectForKey:kKeyID] intValue];

        courseModel.courseNameString = [courseDic objectForKey:kKeyTitle];

        NSArray *lectureArray = [courseDic objectForKey:kKeyLecture];

        for (NSDictionary *lectureDic in lectureArray) {

            LectureModel *lectureModel = [[LectureModel alloc] init];

            NSString *startString = [lectureDic objectForKey:kKeyStart];


            if ([startString isEqualToString:@"8:00"]) {

                lectureModel.lectureNumber = 1;

            }

            else if ([startString isEqualToString:@"9:50"]) {

                lectureModel.lectureNumber = 2;

            }



            lectureModel.location = [lectureDic objectForKey:kKeyWhere];  //@property of location is retain

            [courseModel.lectureArray addObject:lectureModel];

            [lectureModel release];

        }

        [courseArray addObject:courseModel];

        [courseModel release];

    }

}
```

With more tracing i found out that it's

```
lectureModel.location = [lectureDic objectForKey:kKeyWhere];
```

that really matters.
In my LectureModel, location is declared as follow

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *location;

@synthesize location;

- (id)init {
    location = NSLocalizedString(@"未知", nil);
}
```

Delete NSLocalizedString and everything works all right.
Why?

Comment: What line does the double free happen on?

Comment: I have no idea for which line it matters. It just stop in a _pthread_kill in xcode, and when i comment out these codes it works.

Answer (score 0):

Generally working with `NSDictionary` you want to use `valueForKey:` instead of `objectForKey:`, but I don't think that's the problem here. If you flip it back to LLVM, and run Instruments with "Zombies", it should point you to exactly where each free (well, release) is occurring.

Comment: I disagree with the advice to use `-valueForKey:`.  `-objectForKey:` is the native interface of `NSDictionary`. `-valueForKey:` is a KVC addition. It has both additional functionality that one may not want as well as additional restrictions, such as the key having to be a string.

Comment: Ken, I stand corrected. You are absolutely correct there. I would have down voted my original answer, but one cannot vote for one's own answers. I do stand by the Zombie instruction though.

Comment: Oh, I definitely agree with the suggestion to use the Zombies instrument to track memory management errors. :)

Comment: I set NSZombieEnabled in scheme but it didn't show me the error release. Actually it didn't show the double free error in ipad simulator. It only happen in my ipad 2 with 5.0.1...

Comment: Run the Zombie tool, in Instruments, directly with the device (not the simulator).